# Link to support modal from anywhere

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

I'm trying to figure out how I can call `showSupportForm()` from anywhere in my application, not just the dropdown nav that Spark provides out of the box.

I see the method defined in navbar.js -- is there a way to duplicate or extend that method somewhere that would apply globally?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" @click.prevent="showSupportForm" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

And the relevant Vue.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {

    ...

    methods: {
        showSupportForm() {
            Bus.$emit('showSupportForm');
        }
    }
};
```

I've tried moving `@click.prevent="showSupportForm"` around but somewhere these methods must associate with only a subset of the DOM.

Comment: you can call `Bus.$emit("showSupportForm")` from any component (anywhere)

Comment: Exactly `Bus.$emit("showSupportForm")` is the "global" method you want to make "global".